# modifying constants in objective c during run time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, constants

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have the following constants in my header file:

```
#define PREFS_MY_CONSTANT_1 @"bla1"
#define PREFS_MY_CONSTANT_2 @"bla2"
#define PREFS_MY_CONSTANT_3 @"bla3"
...
```

In one of my functions, I'd like to print to the UIbutton one of those strings based on user input, so say the user inputs '1', i would show bla1. Instead of creating a huge switch (i have 100 of those), I am looking for a way to combine the constant with the variable holding the user input, so something like that ideally:

```
NSInteger input;
[button setTitle:PREFS_MY_CONSTANT_{$input} forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is something like that possible? what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just convert the integer to a string and append it to the constant string?

Comment: Is there any relation between the text and the number? That is, does the 1st constant actually have the digit 1, or is "bla1" an example of arbitrary text?

Comment: how can i append string to the constant? i can definitely do the conversion, but no idea how to append like that...

Comment: @JonReid no connection whatsoever...the text can be anything...

Comment: Not at all possible the way you've laid it out.  It appears that you don't understand what you are doing when you `#define` something.  That define will be replaced **before** compilation, so it just a copy and paste really.  The preprocessor will copy and paste all your defines and they will become exactly what you defined them as.  **Then** compilation will begin...and only then will your program run, and those symbols no longer exist.

Comment: good point...so what is a good way to handle 100 of constants that depend on one number input by the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd define a plain C array of NSString literals:

```
static NSString *prefs[] = {
    @"foo",
    @"bar",
    @"baz",
};
```

Either use a 0-based index, or put something in the first entry you won't use, like `nil`. Then `prefs[input]` will give you the string you want.

(The comma after the last entry isn't a mistake. It allows you to add more entries without first having to add a comma. It makes it easier to edit, and makes revision history easier to read.)

The number of elements in a static array can be determined at compile time. I usually use a macro for this:

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

Then you can compare the user input against `ARRAYSIZE(prefs)` to make sure it stays within the range.

Comment: You can't put `nil` into an array!!

Comment: @borrrden, this is not an NSArray. It's a plain C array.

Comment: I know, and C-arrays are NULL terminated.

Comment: No, C strings are NULL terminated.

Answer (score 2):

another way is to use `NSArray` for this.

create an array like this:

```
NSArray *titleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bla1",@"bla2",@"bla3", nil];
```

and you can set the title of button following way:

```
[button setTitle:[titleArray objectAtIndex:input] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This is a valid answer. However, people often use NSArray when a plain array will do. See http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-is-c/

Comment: Be careful though, ARC won't like your example (objective-c pointer in a struct)

Comment: @JonReid thanks alote for the link bro. I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @borrrden ARC doesn't mind an array of object pointers. As for the struct example in my article, just declare the field `__unsafe_unretained` as I explain in a comment.

Comment: Yes, that will work (but you need to be careful about its memory lifetime, and not use it care freely).  Sorry for another comment, but array literals are '[' not '{'

Comment: +1 for being a valid answer. If you use an up-to-date version of Xcode, you can use the new NSArray literal: NSArray *titleArray = @[ @"bla1", @"bla2", @"bla3" ];

Answer (score 0):

For this take `NSString` as

```
NSString *input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PREFS_MY_CONSTANT_%@",input];
[button setTitle:input forState: UIControlStateNormal];

          or
 [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PREFS_MY_CONSTANT_%@",input] forState:     UIControlStateNormal];
```

Let me know if its useful.

Thanks and Regards,
Anil